# Java NIO FileChannel - Empty reads from Android TUN network interface

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nio, android-vpn-service

**Context:** I've recently started using `java.nio` for my project which leverages Android's `VpnService`. In my implementation, I've wrapped the `FileDescriptor` that is returned by the `establish()` method of the `VpnService` into a `java.nio.FileChannel` as shown below.

```
private val outboundNetworkChannel = FileInputStream(fd).channel
```

After that, I've a kotlin coroutine which reads from the `FileChannel` indefinitely and processes the outbound IPv4 / IPv6 packets.

**Issue:** The below mentioned snippet works, but I see a lot of empty reads happening from the `FileChannel` which in turn spins the `while` loop unnecessarily.

```
fun reader() = scope.launch(handler) {
    while (isActive) {
        val pkt = read()
        if(pkt !== DUMMY){
            // Send the read IPv4/IPv6 packet for processing
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun read(): IPDatagram =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val bytes = ByteBufferPool.acquire()
        outboundChannel.read(bytes) // Returns a lot of empty reads with return value as 0
        return@withContext marshal(bytes) // Read IPv4/IPv6 headers and wrap the packet
    }
```

**What I'm looking for:** For a fact, I know that `FileChannel` is a blocking channel and in this case since the channel is backed by a network interface, it might not have packets ready to be read. Is there a better approach with / without `FileChannel` which would lead to a more efficient implementation without wasting precious CPU cycles? I'm open to new ideas as well :)

Comment: How did the `fd` get into non-blocking mode?

Comment: @user207421 Seems like the fd retrieved from Android VpnService by default in non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after digging through the Android Docs for `VpnService`. By default, when a VPN connection is established using `VpnService.Builder` the `fd` is in non-blocking mode. Starting API level 21, one can `setBlocking(true)`.

As stated in the docs for `public VpnService.Builder setBlocking (boolean blocking)`

> Sets the VPN interface's file descriptor to be in
>   blocking/non-blocking mode. By default, the file descriptor returned
>   by establish() is non-blocking.